# Notepad++ regex selecting full file when match is not present

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

This is my first question, so please bear with me while I try and write this as neat and complete as possible!

I am trying to perform a find and replace in Notepad++ using regex, but I am getting some strange results that I do not understand.  Can someone explain where I am going wrong and what I can do to achieve my desired outcome please?

I am using Notepad++ version 6.8.3

I have a number of log files where any customer information has to be redacted.  I have to find the text `Name:` and replace everything after it with `*REDACTED*`  This has to be done using a "Replace in Files".  An example of the specific instances is below:

```
applicantDetailsCommand.firstName: Arnold 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
applicantDetailsCommand.middleName: Judas
applicantDetailsCommand.lastName: Rimmer
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
applicantDetailsCommand.firstName: Dave 
applicantDetailsCommand.middleName: Cinzano Bianco
applicantDetailsCommand.lastName: Lister
blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

In order to do this I started searching using a look-behind thus:
`(?<=Name: ).*$`
which worked fine and found all of the entries after firstName, lastName, etc.  However, in any file that did not contain "Name: ", the whole file matched including all of the lines, so I cannot use this in "Replace in Files" as it will just replace the whole file with "*REDACTED*".

Then I tried to match the string without using look-behind, so searched for `(Name: ).*$` and was going to replace this with `$1\*REDACTED\*`, which worked a treat, but I also discovered that it picked up several other lines, such as "host_name" and "URIName" that I did not want.

At this point I decided to use a group with only the alternative that I actually did want to match, so tried this:
`(first|middle|last|account)Name: .*$`
which started matching full files when neither accountName, firstName, middleName or lastName were present in the file.

I've read through lots of different articles on the tinterweb, but can't find anything that will explain why, when there is no match, the full file is matched.

Any help explaining this would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: What if you make the actual name pattern more specific? Instead of ".*", something like: "\w+(?:\s+\w+)?"

Comment: Unfortunately that is giving me the same result.  Thanks for your input though, I hadn't tried that.

Comment: Another thought might be to try this in Perl or Python. Maybe it's just a bug in NP++...?

Comment: When you run `(first|middle|last|account)Name: .*$` on finding all files, you say it's reporting that it's matching full files. That seems like a bug if you've disabled matches newline since it should be reporting line numbers for each match.

Your regex seems fine. Perhaps you should upgrade to 6.8.7?

Comment: Yeah, when I do a Find in Files, both of the "buggy" searches match all items that they should, but where there is a file with no match, it matches the whole file from start to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug - after much searching I have eventually found this on GitHub:
https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/683

This seems to only happen when using grouping and on files over a certain length.  In one file, splitting it in two allowed me to find no matches of `(?<=\d{8}(,|:) ).*?(?=>|\))`, while keeping the file whole resulted in the regex selecting the whole file.  Strangely, though searching for `(?<=\d{4}(,|:) ).*?(?=>|\))` in the same files worked ok - where the length of digits in the first grouping was 4 instead of 8, otherwise identical!

Also, in another search I modified one of the original regexs in my question from `(first|middle|last|account)Name: .*$` to `(first|middle|last)Name: .*$` and that also started working, as did keeping the same regex and halfing the length of the file.  I also tried `(rst|dle|ast|unt)Name: .*$`, which failed and `(first|middle|account)Name: .*$`, which worked, all of which is pretty random and can't be tied down to any one thing being the problem.

This leads me to believe that there is a fundamental problem in the regex engine and as a result we are now ditching Notepad++ as a solution and are purchasing something else instead as the regex engine cannot be relied upon to be correct.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you disable the checkbox ". finds \r and \n" in the Search and replace window.

Comment: Hi, sorry - I should have said that I have disabled the ".matches newline" checkbox, which I presume is the same? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `Name: .*`
Replace with: `Name: *REDACTED*`

This method should work even if you add the group `(first|middle|last|account)` before the `Find what` pattern. Refer to the gifs below for the exact settings: (I'm using version 6.8.6 by the way)

What happens when file contains your search:
[image]

And what happens when it doesn't:
[image]

Comment: This is working for me when I have a match, but not when there is no match - the whole file gets highlighted.  The file is 140Mb right enough, so not sure if that affects it, but if I search for "firstName" or "lastName" or "accountName" or "middleName" on its own then there is no match.  Possibly it is a bug in the version I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `$` because that means usually *end of string* unless multi-line mode.

However, you don't need multi-line mode. And you have to turn *OFF*
dot means all characters, so it will match anything but line breaks.

Lastly, using `(?<=Name: ).*$` could result in backtracking issues if `Name:`
is not found.

Lose the lookbehind, make it Find: `Name:\h.*` Replace `Name: REDACTED`

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of the .* stopping at a line break.  That being said, the last part of the regex works when there is a match, which is what I'd expect, but I never thought about how it would react when there was no match.  I'll try this when I get into work in the morning.  Do you have an example or explanation of the backtracking issues, if you don't mind?  I'd like to understand _why_ this is happening, rather than just have it fixed for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @Begbie007 -   When you define an assertion, the contents are always run as a seperate context removed from the surrounding context. It just returns true or false to the caller. That means the surrounding context cannot be optimized as a single context. Thus opening the door to potential backtracking problems. That's why something like this `.*(Name: ).*$` fails immediately and something like this `.*(?<=Name: ).*$` takes exponentially longer. As a general rule, its not too good to put lookbehinds at a point where its openended (`.*` on either/both sides).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did realise that using lookaround would take longer, but didn't realise that it wasn't a good idea to have them open ended.  I have tried your suggestion, but I'm seeing the same results as before where `Name:\h.*` works, but selects too much.  And when I try `(account|first|middle|last)Name:\h.*` the whole file with no match is selected, along with line breaks, even although I haven't selected **. matches newline**.

Comment: I've never used np++ but I understand most engines default to Dot _does not_ match line break's. if worse comes to worse, you should be able to use `(?-s)(Name: ).*` which uses an inline modifier to turn _off_ dot-all. Inline modifiers are scoped so they override any global flags. If that doesn't work, I wouldn't use np++ , it's total trash. Another thing to try is `(Name: )[^\r\n]*` where `[^\r\n]` is (almost) the same as `(?-s)`.

Comment: Thanks for your replay again.  I have now installed NP++ 6.8.7 and `(account|first|middle|last)Name:\h.*` now works, so that was obviously a bug in the regex engine. `(Name: )[^\r\n]*` also works in this version, thanks for that.  Being my first question, I'm not sure what I should do with this now.  Should I answer and say it's a bug?  It's already been marked down for some reason, is there a way to find out why? Thanks again for your input.

Comment: In case anyone is reading this thread - installing the latest version has not worked.  It does still fail on files of a certain size.  I tried splitting one of my test files into two and it works perfectly for both halves (regardless of where the split is), but fails and selects/replaces the full file when it is over ~21500 lines (not sure on the Mb size), so seems like a bug under certain circumstances.